# Do I need a company name to publish on Google Play?

Tags: android, game-design

I'm going to upload my Android mobile game on Google Play. But it seems like all games are developed by companies(such as Zynga, and King) and I don't see individual's names as developers. Do I need to register a company name officially? I think it costs a few hundred dollars... If I have to, how and where do I register? or instead of registering a company for a few hundred dollars, if I make a domain website that is named as my company name, would it provide me some protections?
Also, do I need to trademark my game's title as well?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put what you want under developer name. Just make sure its not a trademark being used or registered trademark.  Or just use your real name. It doesn't matter too much.

If you make up a name and brand yourself as it, its a trademark. A website would help prove you used it first.

Comment: I'm no lawyer, but actually publishing a game under that name (whether it's the product name, company name or whatever) should be enough to show that you used it first. It still won't make it obsolete to register the actual trademark, though.

Comment: Yes, you only need to prove you used it first but having a website certainly wouldn't hurt if it ever went to court.

Comment: But how do I know if the studio name I chose is being used? I think one way would be Google search but how can I be sure that Google search lists all studio or company names that are being used? What if the studio name owner does not have a website?

Comment: Ya search around and if there is no evidence that someone is probably using it then you are probably good. If not chances are you will get some sort of legal action letter or something and a chance to change before it ever went to court. Ofcourse I am no lawyer.  (also I have 0 experience with laws outside the usa)